# How to Render Many SpriteKit Nodes at Once?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit to render a large (20 x 20) dot grid that looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to highlight rows or columns based on user input. For example, I'd like to change rows 1-10 to a red color, or columns 5-15 to a blue color.

**What is the most performant way to do this?**

I've tried:

1. Naming each `GridNode` based on the column it's in (e.g. `@"column-4`). Then use `enumerateChildNodesWithName:` with the string as `@"column-n"`, changing the color of each node (by changing `SKShapeNode` setFillColor:) in the enumerate block.
2. Giving all the columns a parent node associated with that column. Then telling the parent node to change its alpha (thus changing the alpha of all its children).
3. Making arrays for the different columns, then looping through each node and changing its color or alpha.

I've tried making the `GridDot` class an `SKEffectNode` with `shouldRasterize:` set to `YES`. I've tried both an `SKShapeNode` and a `SKSpriteNode` as its child. I've also tried taking away the `SKEffectNode` parent and just render an `SKSpriteNode`.

Each of these options makes my whole app lag and makes my framerate drop to ~10 FPS. What is the correct way to change the color/alpha of many nodes (without dropping frames)?

At its heart, the issue is rendering this many nodes, yes?

Comment: How big is your grid?

Comment: 20 x 20 nodes, 1024 x 768 pixels.

Comment: changing the color of a node shouldnt be that expensive...  are you doing this in your update method or something?  400 nodes is a lot though.

Comment: I'm not changing the color in the update loop. Should I post a code snippet? Or do you want to post a code snippet of a bunch of nodes changing color? (That would be most helpful for me!)

Comment: Helpful update: If I render `SKSpriteNode`s with a random texture and switch the textures back and forth, I get 55 FPS. But if I put them into an SKEffectNode (to get `shouldRasterize = YES`), the FPS drops to 10 when switch.

Comment: One final note, setting `[self setShouldEnableEffects:NO]` on the `SKEffectNode` also keeps the FPS high (~50 FPS).

Answer (score 3):

When I faced similar performance problems while using SKShapeNode I came up with this solution:

1. Create `SKShapeNode` with required path and color.
2. Use `SKView`'s method `textureFromNode:crop:` to convert SKShapeNode to an SKTexture
3. Repeat steps 1,2 to create all required textures for a node.
4. Create `SKSpriteNode` from a texture
5. Use created `SKSpriteNode` in your scene instead of `SKShapeNode`
6. Change node's texture when needed using `SKSpriteNode`'s `texture` property

If you have a limited set of collors for your dots, I think this aproach will fit fine for your task.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to @amobi's statement, 400 nodes is **not** a lot. For instance, I have a scene with ~400 nodes and a render time of 9.8ms and 9 draw calls.

If you have 400 **draw calls** though, you should try to reduce that number. To determine the amount of draw calls needed for each frame rendered, implement (some of) the following code. It is actually taken from my own SpriteKit app's ViewController class which contains the SpriteKit scene.

```
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    skView.showsDrawCount = YES;
```

#### Proposed solution

I recommend using [SKView's `ignoresSiblingOrder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/ignoresSiblingOrder). This way, SKSpriteNodes with equal `zPosition` are drawn in **one** draw call, which (for as many nodes/draw you appear to have) is horribly efficient. Set this in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the SKView's ViewController.

```
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
```

I see no reason to burden the GPU with SKEffectNodes in this scenario. They are usually a great way to tank your frame rate.

#### Final thoughts

Basic performance issues mean you have a CPU or a GPU bottleneck. It is difficult to guess which you're suffering from with the current information. You could launch the Profiler, but Xcode itself also provides valuable information when you are running your app in an attached device. FPS in the Simulator is *not* representative for device performance.